# Working with PHP_SELF

Tags: php, class, url

Apologies for the bad title. I need a class to be added to an A tag depending on if the user is on respective page. So to clarify, here is the code:

```
<?php
 $basename = substr(strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])),0,strlen(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))-4);
?>
```

And then I use this code in the menu:

```
<li><a href="index.php"<?php if ($basename == 'index') { echo ' class="current"'; } ?>>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php"<?php if ($basename == 'about') { echo ' class="current"'; } ?>>About</a></li>
```

As you can see, depending on if the user is on index.php or about.php, the class=current will be inserted. This works fine normally, but I am using this code in Wordpress where all the pages are this type of URL: index.php?page_id=X

So the about page URL is index.php?page_id=9, meaning that it will always input the class into the index one. Only solutions that I know of is that the `$basename == 'index'` can in anyway be full URL, e.g. `$basename == 'index.php?page_id=X'` but I couldnt make that work.

Help! Note that I am not experienced with PHP so any replies with detail would be appreciated!

Comment: can you post how you menu links really look like?

Comment: Well, what Im asking is if there is any way to make the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF' to be full URL specific. So that I am required to put $basename == 'index.php?random' instead of $basename == 'index'

Comment: Have you considered using WP's URL rewriting that produces appealing "slug" URLs like `domain.com/about/`?

Comment: It doesnt work unfortunately. Because it detects the original URL regardless!

Answer (score 1):

the current file: `__FILE__`

the current folder of your file `dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR // in 5.3: __DIR__`

Comment: Sorry powtac, could you please elaborate your answer? note that Im not experienced with php so please be specific...!

Comment: what Im asking is if there is any way to make the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF' to be full URL specific. So that I am required to put $basename == 'index.php?random' instead of $basename == 'index'

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = $_GET[page_id];
```

I believe this will return for example 9 if the url is ?page_id=9

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're using Wordpress, I'd suggest that you make a variable towards the top of your page that determines that page's current location.

`$path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

`$current = strtolower($path_parts['filename']);`

Then take that variable and set it in the `<a></a>`, as such:

`<a <?php if($current == 'about') echo 'class="current"'; ?> href="#">About</a>`

Or something like this, it's a start anyway.

additional information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetFileName()
{
    $currentFile = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    $parts = Explode('.', $currentFile);
    return $parts[0];
}
$basename = GetFileName();

<li>
    <a href="index.php" <?php if($basename =="index") echo "class='current'"; ?>>Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="about.php" <?php if($basename =="about") echo "class='current'"; ?>>About</a>
</li
```

>